# Reviewer badge - new?

Tags: discussion, badges

Is the reviewer badge new?

> Reviewer   300 [reviews](https://english.stackexchange.com/review), over 60 actioned

I've only just noticed it and I see that nobody has it (and there are no relevant questions on meta). What does it mean? Is it simply flag 300 posts and have 60 approved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Reviewer badge was rolled out earlier today. It rewards working through the [/review](https://english.stackexchange.com/review) path (note that there are 5 different tabs).

To earn the badge,

- [you must first have the Strunk and White badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111205/your-review-progress-showing-target-badge-that-ive-already-received)
- you must review 1000 posts by clicking the *review answer* or *review question* link and reading through the post.
- you must upvote, downvote, edit, comment on, vote to close, or flag (i.e. take some form of action) at least 200 of the posts you are reviewing

[Note that the numbers have changed since the badge was first deployed because it was raised to become a silver badge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110698/new-bronze-badge-for-reviewing/111329#111329)